# Eclipse plugin development - customizing editor preference

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, plugin.xml

I'm developing eclipse plugin. When right clicking and chose 'preferences' in my editor plugin it shows two trees 'Appearance' & 'Editors'under 'General'. I want to add few more nodes from Window-->preference which shows code templates, content assist and many more. How can i do that? 
I have tried overriding collectContextMenuPreferencePages from AbstractDecoratedTextEditor and try to add extension which are related to code templates, however its not showing in preference page.

```
    @Override
     protected String[] collectContextMenuPreferencePages() {
    return new String[] { "org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages.GeneralTextEditor", //$NON-NLS-1$
            "org.eclipse.ui.editors.preferencePages.Annotations", //$NON-NLS-1$
            "org.eclipse.ui.editors.preferencePages.QuickDiff", //$NON-NLS-1$
            "org.eclipse.ui.editors.preferencePages.Accessibility", //$NON-NLS-1$
            "org.eclipse.ui.editors.preferencePages.Spelling", //$NON-NLS-1$
            "org.eclipse.ui.editors.preferencePages.LinkedModePreferencePage", //$NON-NLS-1$
            "org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages.ColorsAndFonts", //$NON-NLS-1$
            "org.eclipse.ui.editors.templates",
    };
}
```

How can i add General node which is present in window-->preference to editor preference? Thank you.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for the reply. I have already added the java editor but i am unable to see java node in preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the correct method to override.

This is what the Java editor does:

```
@Override
protected String[] collectContextMenuPreferencePages() {
    String[] inheritedPages= super.collectContextMenuPreferencePages();
    int length= 10;
    String[] result= new String[inheritedPages.length + length];
    result[0]= "org.eclipse.jdt.ui.preferences.JavaEditorPreferencePage"; 
    result[1]= "org.eclipse.jdt.ui.preferences.JavaTemplatePreferencePage"; 
    result[2]= "org.eclipse.jdt.ui.preferences.CodeAssistPreferencePage"; 
    result[3]= "org.eclipse.jdt.ui.preferences.CodeAssistPreferenceAdvanced"; 
    result[4]= "org.eclipse.jdt.ui.preferences.JavaEditorHoverPreferencePage"; 
    result[5]= "org.eclipse.jdt.ui.preferences.JavaEditorColoringPreferencePage"; 
    result[6]= "org.eclipse.jdt.ui.preferences.FoldingPreferencePage"; 
    result[7]= "org.eclipse.jdt.ui.preferences.MarkOccurrencesPreferencePage";
    result[8]= "org.eclipse.jdt.ui.preferences.SmartTypingPreferencePage";
    result[9]= "org.eclipse.jdt.ui.preferences.SaveParticipantPreferencePage";
    System.arraycopy(inheritedPages, 0, result, length, inheritedPages.length);
    return result;
}
```

Of course all these ids must be declared using the `org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages` extension point in the usual way.

The first page in the array is the one selected when the preferences are shown.

Comment: After adding these i am still seeing only two nodes(Appearance & editors) in editor's preference page :(. Is there any thing i need to specify in plugin.xml?

Comment: No. The ids (these are page ids not classes) must be declared preference pages but that is all

Comment: I am still seeing only two node under general tree node after adding above code. I have tried adding jdt dependencies in plugin also,however its not working :(

Comment: Well is your method being called at all?